# vim-addons shows only 4 addons

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I guess there are more addons! That's strange, isnt it? I use Ubuntu 12.04. 
How can I increase the amount of addons shown? For the last configuration I used there were much more possible addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that fewer "addons" were ported to the most recent version of [vim-addon-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim-addon-manager/0.4.4). If you want to know *why*, you'll have to ask to the maintainer or [post an issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim-addon-manager).

If you need a particular "addon" that is not available in this package you can simply install it manually.

This is an Ubuntu issue, not a programming or Vim issue. You should ask agin on AskUbuntu.